# Adobe Photoshop CS6 - How to resize image but keep text sharp

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, resize

I have an image:
[image]

that I want to resize larger. So right now, the text is fine. Let me resize it larger:
[image]

Now it's bigger. Problem is, the text - sorry if the screenshot is blurry - it's a screenshot taken with cmd+shift+4 - on the image becomes slightly cut off (the H on the left) and blurry and lighter. The actual image without all the text becomes more blurry, I know that happens, but can I keep the text quality when resizing?

Comment: If the text is a text layer in Photoshop it will not get blurry on resize. If it's part of the image it will get blurrier just like the rest of the image.

Comment: As you can see (right hand side) each text is a text layer. It doesn't get blurry, but it distorts.

Comment: The type isn't "blurry" it's "jagged" -- that would indicate no anti-aliasing. You can adjust anti-aliasing for type layers in the Character panel.

Comment: If i would be recieving CAD drawings with this style of editing scaled, i would conclude that the source is unreliable. But hey what would i know im just a mechanical engineer. Personally i would just redraw this in my cad app (its about as much work as doing the text in the first place)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it just looks like there's no anti-aliasing on the type layers. (Clearly they are type layers, not raster layers)

Highlight the type layers and set an anti-aliasing option on the **Character Panel**.

[image]

Comment: And then resize the image or do this on the resized image's text itself?

Comment: Set this for all the text layers, then resize. However, it shouldn't matter. You can set this after you resize as well if all the layers are still in tact.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to redraw in illustrator? This is a very simply image, will not take more than 15 minutes to do.

You can't just resize a image larger without quality loss.

Also you can try to rasterize it:

**Select the image > Image trace > Sketched Art**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Is a tool inside `Illustrator` to rasterize images to vector elements. So you rasterize it and draw the rest. Its a good pratice to redraw things that you need instead of stretch them. [see this tutorial](http://adobe-illustrator.wonderhowto.com/how-to/redraw-pixelated-image-into-high-quality-vector-image-adobe-illustrator-373041/)

Comment: Because i suggested redrawing it instead of strech. To avoid quality lost.

Comment: Cool! Just keep in mind this tool. Saved me so many times =)

Comment: @TheJuniorProgrammer this is closer to the right answer but irs a bit badly executed. 15 minutes might be too much work if you intend the document as a sketch for one person but if you intend it to be used by more than 2 persons its not so much work after all. But that greatly depends on what you need the image for. Remember you allready worked on  the bad method for about an hour so certainly 15 minutes would have been faster.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own text in Photoshop. The existing text could be erased or colored over with white (use Brush tool). Then just make text layers with text elements (T).

Comment: Look on right hand side......each text is a separate text layer.

Comment: Sorry, somehow missed that. So if you select font layer , ten Edit - Free transform and resize the font layer it gets blurry? What fonts is this?

Comment: 1. I'm not resizing the font layer, I'm resizing the image, and the text layers resize automatically with it.
2. It's Consolas.
3. I already got an answer anyway.